# Problem with forces

Tags: linear-algebra

> A motor boat with the power to steer across a river at $30$ kmph is moving such that the bow is pointed in a northerly direction. The stream is moving eastward at $6$ kmph. The river is $1$ km wide. Where on the opposite side will the boat meet the land?

I wasted enough time on this problem already without getting any answer. Can I know how its 
solution?

All I know is that the position vector of the boat, $t$ hours later, would be: $\vec{r}(t)= (6t)\hat{i}+(30t)\hat{j}$, but I'm not sure where to go from there. In other words, how to take advantage of the info given that the width of the river is $1$ km.

P.S. The book's answer just says: $200$m east of the initial point (and I have no clue what do they mean by east of initial point?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is preferred to write out the question, whenever possible, instead of posting an image with the question. I have removed the image and have written out the question.

Answer (score 1):

When the boat moves 1 km the stream takes it 6/30 km = 0.2 km downstream

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the full logic behind it, consider:

To travel 1 km (to the other side), the boat will take $\dfrac{1\ \text{km}}{30\ \text{km/h}} = \dfrac{1}{30} $ h.

In $\dfrac{1}{30}$ h, the stream would have carried the boat $\dfrac{1}{30}\ \text{h}\times6\ \text{km/h} = 0.2$ km eastwards.

Answer (score 1):

**There is one massive problem with the question. It doesn't tell us where the opposite back is? Is it 1 km to the North of 1 km to the East?**

Velocity has the nice property that it is additive. The velocity of the boat is 30${\bf j}$ km/h. The velocity of the stream is 6${\bf i}$ km/h. Hence the resulting velocity is (6${\bf i}$ + 30${\bf j}$) km/h. Since the velocity is constant, the displacement is (6${\bf i}t$ + 30${\bf j}t$) km.

If it is 1 km to the North we need to solve $6t = 1$, i.e. $t=1/6$ and the final position is (${\bf i}$ + 5${\bf j}$) km. If it is 1 km to the East then we need to solve $30t = 1$, i.e. $t = 1/30$ and position is (0.2${\bf i}$+0.5${\bf j}$) km.

If the bank is to the South or to the West, the boat will never make it. If the bearing is strictly between $0^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$ then other answer are possible.

Comment: The stream is going EAST.
The thing which I still don't understand in here is why the boat will take exactly 1/30 h to reach the other side if the stream will make its trip longer in distance (as it pushes it towards east of north) thus there must be more time required than what was actually calculated (1/30) to reach the other side!

Comment: Also I think 0.2i+0.5j is a typo on your part coz it should read 0.2i+j (if t = 1/30)